# how uevents get triggered in kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, udev

uevents has been sent from kernel space to user space through netlink socket.

In kernel, there must be something trigger uevent.

I guess there are two possibilities:

1. Hardware interrupt - this means, once hardware interruption happened, kernel sends event to user space to signal that there is some events happened.
2. software polling - this means, there is always a daemon to check these file system to see if there is anything changed. If so, then update these info to upper layer.

Could anyone provide your feedback?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't agree with you about polling. `uevent` is event-based, so there is no polling.

Triggering uevent happened in many cases and I would rather start with figuring out what uevent **types** are exist?

Little searching and here you go - in [include/linux/kobject.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/kobject.h?v=3.13#L51)

```
enum kobject_action {
    KOBJ_ADD,
    KOBJ_REMOVE,
    KOBJ_CHANGE,
    KOBJ_MOVE,
    KOBJ_ONLINE,
    KOBJ_OFFLINE,
    KOBJ_MAX
};
```

So it's

- Add event
- Remove event
- Change event
- Move event
- Online event
- Offline event

`KOBJ_MAX` is special and marks and of enum.

There are 2 functions that actually sends uevent - `kobject_uevent` and `kobject_uevent_env`. These functions are called with on of the actions listed above.

Finally, to answer your questions. There are no predefined cases that will trigger uevent. If you search for calls of [`kobject_uevent`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/C/ident/kobject_uevent) and [`kobject_uevent_env`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/C/ident/kobject_uevent_env) you will see that it's happens in various callbacks in different unrelated kernel subsystems.

**uevent is kernel facility to unify notifications from various unrelated drivers**. So I think there are no well known list of things that will trigger uevent.

Comment: Thanks. Can I think this as an item 1? Which is mostly triggered by hardware interrupt.

Comment: Maybe. Hardware interrupts causes mostly `KOBJ_ADD/REMOVE`. But there are `KOBJ_CHANGE` that could be triggered by some kernel process or userspace daemon.

Comment: Thanks. Would you mind to provide an example about KOBJ_CHANGE which is triggered by some events without hardware interrupts?

Comment: Example from btrfs: in fs/btrfs/volumes.c there is a call to [`btrfs_kobject_uevent`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/btrfs/volumes.c#L1695) from `btrfs_rm_device` and `btrfs_rm_device` is called from `btrfs_ioctl_rm_dev`. This event is not hardware based - it's ioctl handler.

Comment: Thanks! This is a great example to know.