# How to transfer data from kernel to applicaiton?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, adc, iio

I have an ADC device, I wrote a driver for it, the driver works well. I want to send the sample data from the driver to the application.

I choose *fasync* way, using a SIGIO signal to notify the application can read data from the driver. But I found sometimes the application does not respond to the signal, especially the signal frequency is high(about 1000hz). And when I do some other work such as using chrome, it will influence the signal response.

In summary, my method is very unstable.

Do you have some stable method or advice about transferring data to the application in a high-frequency situation?

Comment: If driver is written correctly, I.e. as IIO one, `libiio` provides all necessary support.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20975566/what-is-the-best-way-to-communicate-a-kernel-module-with-a-user-space-program . Just do a character block device or maybe better procfs and let it poll.